# Yii2: GridView © Kartik ссылки с pjax

Tags: php, yii2, gridview, pjax

Если использовать параметр pjax:

```
    GridView::widget([
        'pjax' => true
```

и если в **columns** в одно из полей добавить ссылку **Html::a** с параметром *target=_blank*,
то клик на ней будет обрабатываться pjax и не откроется страница в новой вкладке. Можно, конечно, переходить с помощью js onclick window.open, но хотелось бы, чтобы была ссылка стандартная.. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашлось, нужно добавить параметр data-pjax = 0 к ссылке:

```
return Html::a('Text', 'link', ['target' => '_blank', 'data-pjax' => '0']);
```